# How to Capture access_token / Bearer Token in ASP.NET Web API when generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, bearer-token

I am trying to achieve the Access Token which is bearer token, when generated by ASP.NET Web API on Login

This is the request

http://localhost:0000/token

```
username=Over@Flow.com&Password=stackWorld#1grant_type=password
```

---

and this is the response you get from the Server

```
{
    "access_token": "Some Big Token",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 1209599,
    "userName": "ok@ok.com",
    ".issued": "Mon, 01 May 2017 14:32:32 GMT",
    ".expires": "Mon, 15 May 2017 14:32:32 GMT"
}
```

What i want to know is how can i get this token when being generated from my server and save it to my database

The token is being generated by asp.net Identity Model on the Project Folder > Providers > ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs File

This has a Method Name **GrantResourceOwnerCredentials** which is handling all the token generation but i am not able to get the bearer token which it generates

Comment: The logic of token generation is not written by you? How the token is being generated?

Comment: GrantResourceOwnerCredentials is the method which handles it all and is provided by microsoft

Comment: And do you have any code in between before the result is returned to the client ?

Comment: @user2715389 how are you trying to access it on the client side? i.e via Javascript, JQuery etc?